How do I restrict recording of youtube app package using mediaprojection api from my app?
How do I restrict recording of youtube app package using mediaprojection api from my app? I created screencast application using mediaprojection api, it records everything from screen, I want to restrict apps like youtube, whatsapp etc. I tried using devicepolicymanager but didn't worked. Here's my Mediaprojection service class code, targetsdk: api 34

public class MediaProjectionService extends Service {

    private String TAG = MediaProjectionService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String RESULT_CODE = "RESULT_CODE";
    private static final String DATA = "DATA";
    private static final String ACTION = "ACTION";
    private static final String START = "START";
    private static final String STOP = "STOP";
    private static final String SCREENCAST = "SCREENCAST";
    private static int IMAGES_PRODUCED;
    private MediaProjection mediaProjection;
    private String dir;
    private ImageReader imageReader;
    private Handler handler;
    private Display display;
    private VirtualDisplay virtualDisplay;
    private int density;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int rotation;
    private OrientationChangeCallback orientationChangeCallback;

    private static boolean isStartCommand(Intent intent) {
        return intent.hasExtra(RESULT_CODE) && intent.hasExtra(DATA)
                && intent.hasExtra(ACTION) && Objects.equals(intent.getStringExtra(ACTION), START);
    }

    private static boolean isStopCommand(Intent intent) {
        return intent.hasExtra(ACTION) && Objects.equals(intent.getStringExtra(ACTION), STOP);
    }

    public static Intent startIntent(Context context, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MediaProjectionService.class);
        intent.putExtra(ACTION, START);
        intent.putExtra(RESULT_CODE, resultCode);
        intent.putExtra(DATA, data);
        return intent;
    }

    public static Intent stopIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MediaProjectionService.class);
        intent.putExtra(ACTION, STOP);
        return intent;
    }

    private static int getVirtualDisplay() {
        return DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY | DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC;
    }

    private class ImageAvailableListener implements ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try (Image image = imageReader.acquireLatestImage()) {
                if (image != null) {
                    Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                    ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
                    int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
                    int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
                    int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * width;

                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width + rowPadding / pixelStride, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

                    fos = new FileOutputStream(dir + "/myscreen_" + IMAGES_PRODUCED + ".png");
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

                    IMAGES_PRODUCED++;
                    Log.e(TAG, "captured image: " + IMAGES_PRODUCED);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (fos != null) {
                    try {
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private class OrientationChangeCallback extends OrientationEventListener {

        OrientationChangeCallback(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            final int rotation = display.getRotation();
            if (rotation != MediaProjectionService.this.rotation) {
                MediaProjectionService.this.rotation = rotation;
                try {
                    if (virtualDisplay != null) virtualDisplay.release();
                    if (imageReader != null) imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null);

                    createVirtualDisplay();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class MediaProjectionStopCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            Log.e(TAG, "Media projection stopped!");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Media projection stopped!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (virtualDisplay != null) virtualDisplay.release();
                    if (imageReader != null) imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null);
                    if (orientationChangeCallback != null) orientationChangeCallback.disable();
                    mediaProjection.unregisterCallback(MediaProjectionStopCallback.this);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        File externalFilesDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
        if (externalFilesDir != null) {
            dir = externalFilesDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/screenshots/";
            File storeDirectory = new File(dir);
            if (!storeDirectory.exists()) {
                boolean success = storeDirectory.mkdirs();
                if (!success) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "failed to create file storage directory");
                    stopSelf();
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed to create file directory");
            stopSelf();
        }

        // start capture handling thread
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                handler = new Handler();
                Looper.loop();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (isStartCommand(intent)) {
            Pair<Integer, Notification> notification = NotificationUtils.getNotification(this);
            startForeground(notification.first, notification.second);

            // start projection
            int resultCode = intent.getIntExtra(RESULT_CODE, Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
            Intent data = intent.getParcelableExtra(DATA);
            startProjection(resultCode, data);
        } else if (isStopCommand(intent)) {
            stopProjection();
            stopSelf();
        } else {
            stopSelf();
        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void startProjection(int resultCode, Intent data) {
        MediaProjectionManager mpManager =
                (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        if (mediaProjection == null) {
            mediaProjection = mpManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
            if (mediaProjection != null) {
                // display metrics
                density = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
                WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

                createVirtualDisplay();

                orientationChangeCallback = new OrientationChangeCallback(this);
                if (orientationChangeCallback.canDetectOrientation()) {
                    orientationChangeCallback.enable();
                }

                mediaProjection.registerCallback(new MediaProjectionStopCallback(), handler);
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopProjection() {
        if (handler != null) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mediaProjection != null) {
                        mediaProjection.stop();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //recreate virtual display based on device resolution
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    private void createVirtualDisplay() {
        width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        height = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);
        virtualDisplay = mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(SCREENCAST, width, height,
                density, getVirtualDisplay(), imageReader.getSurface(), null, handler);
        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageAvailableListener(), handler);
    }
}


